# form valueChanges on second step only

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using [mat-stepper with single form](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#using-a-single-form). I have two steps only.
I want to do API request on every input value change but only when the user is on the second step.
how can I achieve that?

**.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({
          "product": ['lifeci', Validators.required],
          "gender": ['', Validators.required],
          "birthDate": ['', [Validators.min(18), Validators.max(50)]],
          "payFrequency": [12],
          "subLimit": ['100']
        }),
        this._formBuilder.group({
          "currency": ['USD', Validators.required],
          "amount": ['15000', Validators.required],
          "period": ['', Validators.required],
        }),
      ])
    });
    //send request onchange
    this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.onSubmit();
    });
  }
```

for the HTML I am using the same structure as from documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe only to the second step part of the form

```
(this.formGroup.get('formArray') as FormArray).at(1).valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.onSubmit();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, add an extra variable `selectedTabIndex` in your TS.

```
const selectedTabIndex = 0;
```

**Then**, add `selectedIndex` input directive to your stepper like:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex">
```

**Finally**, change in the `valueChanges` subscription as:

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    if (selectedTabIndex === 1) {// That means second tab is selected
        this.onSubmit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To clearly understand on which form you operate it is good practice to extract from each step "semi-form" into getter.

In your component file declare enum or type that describes each step.

```
enum FormStep {
  BorrowerDetails = 0,
  LoanDetails = 1
}
```

In your component class declare getters for each step.

```
private get debeterDetailsForm() {
  return (this.formGroup.get('formArray') as FormArray).at(FormStep.BorrowerDetails);
}

private get loanDetailsForm() {
  return (this.formGroup.get('formArray') as FormArray).at(FormStep.LoanDetails);
}
```

Then in your component after declaring form you can use declared getters.

```
this.loanDetailsForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.onSubmit());
```

Comment: I agree on this one, but maybe add a debounceTime and switchmap. This really can spam the API when doing a request on each letter if the user types fast. Also not really recommended to make a http-request inside a subscribe :) Chain them instead.